# Physical device in subnet of virtual networks

Tags: cisco, routing, virtual

I was wondering if it's possible to connect a physical Raspberry to a NUC running several virtual machines on an ESXi environment.

The network is setup as follows:

[image: Current network setup]

I want my physical device to be 'connected' at the red arrow. Is it possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server/VM configurations, and questions about consumer-grade devices, are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a way to enable my virtual router to act as router for the physical device, solving my problem.

EDIT:
As Teun Vink has a valid point I'll try to explain my solution.

I have removed the OpenSense Virtual router from the network and connected the Cisco router directly to the vSwitch0 interface (VM network). I have put the vSwitch0 interface in promniscious mode so the virtual cisco router is able to send DHCP requests trough it.

Then I have removed the internet cable from my ESXi NUC, which removed the connection to the internet for the vSwitch0 (which in my case, does not matter).

After doing this I have connected a physical switch to the internet port of the ESXi NUC. Since the virtual Cisco router is able to send DHCP requests (and do the routing stuff) over the vSwitch0 (promniscious mode) and my physical raspberry can be connected to the physical switch, they are now able to communicate.

Any physical or virtual device connected to either vSwitch0 or the physical switch will receive routing and ip addresses from the virtual cisco router. They are in the same subnet, which allows them to communicate. None of them, however, have an internet conenction (which, again, does not matter in my case)

So it looks like this:

[image: Altered network]

Note that the cisco router is also virtual, but just not in picture

Comment: Please share your solution so this post has any use to others.

Comment: @TeunVink You are right. Edited my post (: